# How can I set the return value of an awaited task at any time from anywhere?

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await

I'm having a hard time formulating a good title, but I would like to do something like this:

```
Dim inputValue As Object = Nothing

For Each p As Phase in Cycle.Phases
    Dim returnedValue As PhaseResult = Await p.Run()
    inputValue = returnedValue.inputForNextPhase
Next
```

Now, `p.Run` may cause any number of things to happen. For example, it could start a timer. When that timer finishes, another timer may be started, and so on. I want `p.Run` to return a *promise* that a return value will be provided at some point in the future. But that return value will not be returned by `p.Run` itself. Instead, I want to save a reference to the `Task(Of Object)` object that is returned by `p.Run`, and when the `Phase` object decides that it's done its duties, it will set the return value of the `Task(Of Object)` instance in a completely different method (for example in an event handler).

I want something similar to:

```
Private Sub OnSuccess(e as EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Succeeded(Me, e)
    Me.TaskObjectCreatedEarlier.Return(Me.StuffIHaveGathered)
End Sub
```

I then want the loop to continue, passing `StuffIhaveGathered` as an argument to the next `Phase` instance's `Run` function.

I tried to look into implementing `INotifyCompletion` and using a custom awaiter of sorts, but couldn't find any relevant articles on the internet.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. C# examples are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` for this:

```
// Create a TCS and return its task.
// Note: no "Async" because we return the task object directly
//   instead of having the compiler create one for us.
_tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
return _tcs.Task;
```

Later, complete the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
object result = ...;
_tcs.TrySetResult(result); // completes the task that was returned earlier.
```

Also see:

- [Wrapping events with tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap).

Comment: Any particular reason you use the "Try" form while ignoring the return value?

Comment: Some TCS usage allows completion from multiple code paths. Using the `Try*` methods implements a "first-in wins" system.